# target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS`

Tags: xcode, cordova, cocoa, build

I get this error message after I installed Cordova-plugin-googleplus

'''
The `[Release]` target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-proj/Pods-proj.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
'''

and indeed in compilation a framework cannot been found.(GtmSessionFetcher

I tried adding in other linker flags in Xcode build setting the $(inherited) as a new line under release and under Debug but no luck.

Any other ideas?